# Add value in textbox on checkbox check

Tags: jquery, html, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I've got 3 checkboxes and I want to fill in a database query based on the checked checkboxes. What I've got so far is , just enough for it to search based on 1 of the textboxes, but I want to be able to add unlimited amounts of categories to search from.

Here are my 3 checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CorrectionConsultantYN" value="60" />
<input type="checkbox" id="ProcessingAnalyzYN" value="10" />
<input type="checkbox" id="ProcessingConsultantYN" value="0" />
```

Here's my textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchValue" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" class="form-control form-control-pireus"></asp:TextBox>
```

And my function so far:

```
$("[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#SearchValue").val($(this).val());
    }
    else {
        $("#SearchValue").val();
    }
});
```

What I want the final result to be is something like `select * from` something where there's `textbox` 1 value, `textbox` 2 value and so on.

I'm using Sql Server here's the code behind for searching for only 1 checkbox.

```
if (RequestFilter.SelectedValue == "krStatus")
    {
        query += " and d.krStatus";
    }
if (FilterOp.SelectedValue == "equals")
    {
        query += "='" + SearchValue.Text + "'";
    }
    else if (FilterOp.SelectedValue == "contains")
    {
        query += " like '%" + SearchValue.Text + "%'";
    }
    else if (FilterOp.SelectedValue == "begins")
    {
        query += " like '" + SearchValue.Text + "%'";
    }
    else if (FilterOp.SelectedValue == "ends")
    {
        query += " like '%" + SearchValue.Text + "'";
    }
```

Here is how the whole query looks at the end:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY d.[Id]) AS RowNum,
d.Id as ROWID, d.*,  CAST(e.XmlLos AS varchar(max)) AS XMLD , CASE WHEN b.Category = 2 THEN 'Ипотечен' WHEN b.Category = 3 THEN 'Овърдрафт' WHEN b.Category = 4 THEN 'Кредитна карта'  ELSE 'Потребителски'  END AS Category, LTRIM(RTRIM(b.Name)) AS ProdName, LTRIM(RTRIM(f.Name)) AS StatusName, LTRIM(RTRIM(g.Ccy)) AS CcyName, (CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(d.BankTragerId)) = '*' THEN '0000' ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(d.BankTragerId)) END +'-'+ CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(d.KrDepartament)) = '*' THEN '0000' ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(d.KrDepartament)) END +'-'+ CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(d.ProductExId)) = '*' THEN '0000' ELSE LTRIM(RTRIM(d.ProductExId)) END +'-'+ CASE WHEN (d.Id > 9999999) THEN CAST(d.Id as NVARCHAR(max)) ELSE RIGHT('0000000'+CAST(d.Id AS NVARCHAR(7)),7) END ) AS ApplicationId, ISNULL((SELECT y.DisplayName from bsUsers y WHERE y.UserID=d.UserId),' ') AS USERIDNAME, KrQueueUp, UserProcess, ISNULL((SELECT y.DisplayName from bsUsers y WHERE y.UserID=d.UserProcess),' ') AS USERPROCESSNAME 
FROM [dbo].[Krdocs_Details] d, [dbo].[Products] b, [dbo].[Krdocs] e, [dbo].[Statuses] f, [dbo].[Currency] g  WHERE d.Id=e.Id AND f.Code=d.KrStatus AND d.Product=b.Id AND d.CcyId = g.Id and d.KrStatus like 60
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, what do you want  sql query, what db you are using

Comment: Please add more explanation to your question.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: @AlexanderHristov what exactly you want ? what is your end result

Comment: I've updated it with a example query.